# Custom android gradle plugin unable to load class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to build a custom gradle plugin, but it always failed when I let the root proj apply the plugin.

```
ERROR: Unable to load class 'com.ucloud.android.plugin.UpluginImpl'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

My plugin class is:

```
package com.ucloud.android.uplugin

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class UpluginImpl implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task("Test Ucloud Task") << {
            println("********************* Task *********************")
        }
    }
}
```

My build.gradle file of plugin module is:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation gradleApi()
    implementation localGroovy()
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = "8"
targetCompatibility = "8"

group = 'com.ucloud.android.plugin'
version = '1.0.2'
archivesBaseName='ucloud-plugin'

uploadArchives { //当前项目可以发布到本地文件夹中
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: uri('/Users/joshua/.m2/repository/')) //定义本地maven仓库的地址
        }
    }
}
```

My module/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/***.properties

```
implementation-class = com.ucloud.android.plugin.UpluginImpl
```

I even tried uninstall Android Studio completely, remove all cache dirs of the Studio. And remove my .gradle dir。 The error still be here...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing apply plugin.. so gradle would know where plugin can be found:

```
apply plugin: UpluginImpl
```

Comment: Ok, then check if you have anything in this folder: **/Users/joshua/.m2/repository/** Probably you did upload plugin here? If not Upload archive first.. and after that check also if you are using repositories same as you have it in plugin, this one maven { url '/Users/joshua/.m2/repository/' }.. check also if folder path is ok..